# Can anyone tell me how to perform audio recording in adts raw aac format in ice cream sandwich

Tags: audio-recording, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, aac, adts

Ice cream sandwich has new feature of supporting audio recording in adts raw aac format but i am not able to find the api for it on developer.android.com?

Can anyone tell me how i can develop an application for recording audio in adts raw aac format on ice cream sandwich?

Answer (score 0):

Set Media recorder output format to AAC_ADTS ... more details are here ..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html

Hope it helps you...